# More information about PTAM algorithm

Tags: ros, ptam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am student in vision systems and I would like to go deeper in PTAM algorithm.
Where could I found more informations about this algorithm?

Best regard.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/104386/more-information-about-ptam-algorithm/) by [bird12358](https://answers.ros.org/users/9116/bird12358/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-11-25**:
Have you considered asking the authors of the paper / algorithm directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For ROS part, there is a package that you can check [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ptam)

you can check the paper of ptam [here](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Egk/publications/KleinMurray2007ISMAR.pdf)

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2013-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0